# Add a photo your PyQt5 user UI

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to open a photo and add it into my PyQt5 user UI but app closes when i open the photo, what should i do?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import PIL
import os



class Photo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open a Photo")
        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel("")


        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.button)
        v_box.addWidget(self.title)


        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addLayout(v_box)
        h_box.addStretch()



        self.setLayout(h_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Photo")

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.show()

    def click(self):
        open_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open the File",os.getenv("HOME"))

        with open(open_file[0], "w") as file: 
            self.title.setText(file.write())
            


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

photo = Photo()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Start your code from the terminal so you can see the error when it crashes

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `self.title.setText(file.write())` to do? It won't add any photo to the UI

Comment: What should i use instead of 'self.title.setText(file.write())' ?

Comment: Like I said, what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: I am expecting that add a photo which is users wants to the UI

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç If you want to display an *image*, how would you expect that functions named "setText" and "write" would achive that?!? Don't try random things that make absolutely ***no*** sense. Look for what you want to do, and [read the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html).

Comment: Don't be that angry, i have just started PyQt5, isn't it normal to make a mistakes or?

Comment: We're trying to highlight that the "write" method of a file object does not "read" an image. And "setText" of the UI's title does not "display" an image. So, it seems you've copied this line of code without understanding what it does? Or why that would cause an error (which you've not shown)?

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç I'm not angry, and the point here is not about making mistakes. Confusing or not understanding *one* function is a mistake. Doing that twice in the same line is another story. In programming, choosing names is an extremely important aspect, because when you write code you should be able to focus on what you want to do, not being distracted on remember how it's written; and the same goes in reading code. Luckily, python usually has very clear names (one of its main focus is about *readability*); Qt is also extremely verbose with names (sometimes even too much).

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç And that's because their developer *wisely* choose those names to make things easier (and better) for all their users, following the principles explained above. A good portion of writing code (especially for others) is about writing *good code*. Programming languages are, indeed, languages: people should be able to understand them. If a function is named "write", it means that it *writes* something (while what you want is to *read* a file); and if a function is called "set text" it certainly it is not intended to "show an image".

Answer (score 1):

```
    with open(open_file[0], "w") as file: 
        self.title.setText(file.write())
```

you cant setText to a function (file.write())

by the way the code is written in this section - it gives the impression you're saving a file.. perhaps you want:

```
    with open(open_file[0], "rb") as file: 
        self.title.setText(open_file[0])
        file_contents = file.read()
```

this will read the file contents into a variable, but even then you should be using something like QImage or QPixmap to open a file directly, only using the dialog to get a reference path to the file the user wants to open:

```
filePath = open_file[0]
self.title.setText(filePath)
selected_image = QImage(filePath)
```

selected_image is now a QImage copy of the file selected by the user, no reading of the file needed as it's contained within the QImage library

Comment: File mode should probably be `rb` for an image file

Comment: Thanks for answer but when i add the codes what you write,  the app still closes. Can you please send me full codes?

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç the code above works, there's absolutely no need for the "full code", the answer is more than valid, it's expected from you that you're able to integrate it. If it doesn't work, as already said, start the program in a terminal, see the error, and do research on that.

Comment: good point, i changed my answer - last example when i remembered that it shouldnt be needed as QImage only requires filepath and not bytes, i think thats loadFromData.

but good point, ill update second example